# Extract windows user login details while opening a local website and authenticate

Tags: java, windows

How do I take the windows login details and open a local website on my computer?

Further explanation:

1. Successful windows user login means successful website login(done automatically)
2. In the website it must be shown "Welcome Nandy, Deepayan ". This profile name is being taken from the windows profile login name.

Any idea, How do I achieve this?
I am making this website using J2EE and servlets.

Comment: I assume you are looking for the "NTLM Authentication scheme". Try this link: http://www.luigidragone.com/software/ntlm-authentication-in-java

Comment: The link you cite is a horrible hack and a total security fail. [Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com/) is the proper way to do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is possible with [Integrated Windows Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication). You will need to find out if your web stack `supports the same`.

Quote from wiki:

> Integrated Windows Authentication uses the security features of
>   Windows clients and servers. Unlike Basic or Digest authentication,
>   initially, **it does not prompt users for a user name and password**. The
>   current **Windows user information on the client computer is supplied by
>   the web browser** through a cryptographic exchange involving hashing
>   with the Web server. If the authentication exchange initially fails to
>   identify the user, the web browser will prompt the user for a Windows
>   user account user name and password.

Look for further information on the following links:
[Single-Sign-On (SSO) in Java Platform using Active Directory](http://webmoli.com/2009/08/29/single-sign-on-in-java-platform/) &
[Integrated Windows Authentication in Java](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Do you have any good article on how I can achieve this "cryptographic exchange involving hashing with the Web server"?